# How to update data on tableView and synchronize timer in 2 view controllers Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer

I am making a timer app. I have 2 view controllers, one has the timer (the second view controller) as shown below

```
protocol PassBack {
    func passBackData(minutesDone: Int)
}

class SessionTimerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: PassBack?
    var timeLeft = 10
    var totalTT = ""
    var timer = Timer()
    var minutesDone = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeAllocated.text = "\(totalTT) minutes"
        timeLeft = Int(totalTT)! * 60
        
        let hours = timeLeft / 3600
        let minutes = timeLeft / 60 % 60
        let seconds = timeLeft % 60
        remainingTime.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
  }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.passBackData(minutesDone: minutesDone)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    func toggleTimer(on: Bool) {
        
        if on {
           
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {
                timer in

                self.timeLeft -= 1
                
                self.minutesDone = (Int(self.totalTT)! * 60) - self.timeLeft
                    
                    let hours = self.timeLeft / 3600
                    let minutes = self.timeLeft / 60 % 60
                    let seconds = self.timeLeft % 60
                    self.remainingTime.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
                    
                    if self.timeLeft == 0 {
                    
                    timer.invalidate()
            }
        } else {
            
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have managed to successfully pass the minutesDone back to the first view controller.
The code in the first view controller is as follows.

```
class TreatmentTimeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var nameTime = [NameTime]()
    var treatmentTime1 = 10
    var statusUpdate1 = "Not treated"
    var minutesDone1 = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TreatmentTimeCell", for: indexPath) as? TreatmentTimeTableViewCell
            
            cell?.patientName?.text = nameTime[indexPath.row].patientName
            cell?.treatmentTime?.text = "\(nameTime[indexPath.row].treatmentTime)"
           
            let value = nameTime[indexPath.row].treatmentTime
            var value2 = nameTime[indexPath.row].minutesDone
            
            value2 = minutesDone1
            
            if value2 == value {
                      statusUpdate1 = "Treatment completed"
                  } else if value2 == 0 {
                      statusUpdate1 = "Not treated"
                  } else if value2 < value {
                      statusUpdate1 = "Currently treating"
                  }
            
            cell?.minutesDone?.text = "\(value2)"
            cell?.statusUpdate?.text = statusUpdate1
            
            return cell!
            
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SessionTimerViewController") as? SessionTimerViewController
            
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            
            let value = nameTime[indexPath.row].treatmentTime
        
            treatmentTime1 = value
        
            destinationVC?.totalTT = "\(treatmentTime1)"
            destinationVC?.delegate = self
            
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC!, animated: true)
            
        }

extension TreatmentTimeViewController: PassBack {
    func passBackData(minutesDone: Int) {
        
        minutesDone1 = minutesDone / 60 % 60
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

I am having the following issues which I need help with

1. When the minutesDone (or rather minutesDone1) is passed back it updates on every cell. How do I get it to update on the particular indexPath.row I need.
2. I would like minutesDone1 to continuously update in the `TreatmentTimeViewController`. Do I need to set up another timer or is there a way of synchronizing the timer in the 2 view controllers? If so what is the best way to do it?
3. The last issue is when I click on the cell to go to `SessionTimerViewController`, that is at `didSelectRowAt`, it always starts the timer again. How do I go about putting a condition that if it is already running, it should just continue where it left?
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. use the update row method of the table view.
2. Use the observer receiver pattern to implement this feature.
3. Save previous time condition locally in user defaults and make a global boolean variable (usually using singleton class) to restrict the condition.